# The Google Sheets "On Form Submit" trigger is sending blank emails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I wrote a very simple script to send an email with some basic data (included). The script works perfectly with every trigger except "On Form Submit", which is the one I really need. Is there something I am missing or should have done differently?

```
function sendEmails() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var mainSheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet()
  var recipient = 'scorbin@alliedinvsys.com'
  var subject = mainSheet.getRange(2, 11).getValue()
  var body = mainSheet.getRange(3, 12).getValue()
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)
}
```

[Event Log Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzlWQ.png)

Comment: Did you try to save the trigger again after you edit your code, i have similar issue in the past also, but now is fixed.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried re-saving and totally deleting and re-adding the trigger all with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me when I submit a form using the form submit trigger for a spreadsheet.  I hope that you realize that there is one for the form and and for the the spreadsheet with a linked sheet.

```
function onMyNewFormSubmit(e) {
  const subject = "This is my subject";
  const body = `TimeStamp: ${e.values[0]} One: ${e.values[1]} Two: ${e.values[2]}`;
  MailApp.sendEmail(gobj.globals.privateemail,subject,body);
}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like when it is triggered, the relevant info is being pulled, but then it shows nothing being populated in he subject and body.

Comment: I added an image link of the event log to the original question.

Comment: The second Logger.log() clearly shows that there is nothing in the subject or the body.  Are you completely sure that you understand how to use the Logger.  I'm beginning to doubt that.

Comment: Clearly the problem is in these two lines `var subject = mainSheet.getRange(2, 11).getValue()
  var body = mainSheet.getRange(3, 12).getValue()`

Comment: I don't really care about the why.  The reality is that the Logger shows that there's nothing in your variables subject or body.  You're the one with the spreadsheet and all of the data.  Go figure it out.

Comment: Personally, I would get the data directly from the form submission event object.  It's a waist of time getting it from the spreadsheet and what's worse is that if you get mutliple simultaneous submissions you will problem get the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone experiencing similar issues, I found the issue in my specific case at least. I have the data being transcribed from the response capturing sheet, to another sheet in the same workbook so the data ranges remain constant (every time a new response is submitted, it adds a new row to the sheet). So the script line:   var mainSheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet() works with all other triggers because the transcribed sheet was the one i was working with when they were triggered. Since the "On Form Submit" trigger happens when answers are populating on the response page, that is the active sheet at the time of the trigger and I was getting blank emails because there was nothing in the reference cells called out in the script on that particular sheet. Sorry I was so wordy.